# Trying to create a multi threaded C program that prints a string in reverse order

Tags: c, function, pointers, void-pointers

I am working on an assignment for my C coding class that requires us to create multiple threads that run different functions. As to ease my confusion, I am trying to do the program one thread at a time, but I am having some trouble. Here is my code:

```
   #include <pthread.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <math.h>
   #include <string.h>

   void * print_string_in_reverse_order(void *str)
   {
       // This function is called when the new thread is created
       printf("%s","In funciton start_routine(). Your string will be printed backwards.");
       char *word[50];
       strcpy (*word, (char *)str);

       int length = strlen(*word);

       for (int x = length-1; x >= 0; x--){
          printf("%c",&word[x] );
       }
       pthread_exit(NULL); // exit the thread
   }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* The main program creates a new thread and then exits. */
    pthread_t threadID;
    int status;
    char input[50];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("In function main(): Creating a new thread\n");
    // create a new thread in the calling process
    // a function name represents the address of the function
    status = pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, print_string_in_reverse_order, (void *)&input);

    // After the new thread finish execution
    printf("In function main(): The new thread ID = %d\n", threadID);

    if (status != 0) {
            printf("Oops. pthread create returned error code %d\n", status);
            exit(-1);
    }
    printf("\n");

    exit(0);
 }
```

At present, while I have no compiler errors, it does not print anything and does not appear to reverse the string in any way. I am very new to C so I assume it is something like errors with my pointers, but even after several changes and attempts I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It's odd to have an array of character pointers — `char *word[50];` — in the function.  First steps first — make the function work single-threaded.  Then use it with a thread.  Don't forget to wait for the thread to complete — `pthread_join()` — before exiting.

Comment: the posted code results in several warnings.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Oops. pthread create returned error code %d\n", status);`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using: `fprintf( stderr, "Oops. pthread create returned error code %d\n", status );`

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` since the parameters are not used, the compiler will output two warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`:  `int main( void )`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", input);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values)  the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversions'  In the current scenario: `if( scanf("%s", input) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for input failed\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`   2) when using the input format conversion specifiers: `%s` and/or `%[...]` always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer as those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 50.  'magic' numbers make the code more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement or `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 2):

If `word` is supposed to be a `char` array holding a string, the line

`char *word[50];`

should be changed to:

`char word[50];`

Also, the line

`strcpy (*word, (char *)str);`

should be changed to:

`strcpy (word, (char *)str);`

In additon, the line

`printf("%c",&word[x] );`

should be changed to:

`printf("%c", word[x] );`

Also, before returning from function `main()`, you must wait for the created thread to finish executing, by adding the following line:

`pthread_join( threadID, NULL );`

Otherwise, your thread may be terminated prematurely.

Comment: @kaylum: Thanks, I have added it to my answer.