# How to iterate through an pointer that holds an array in C

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

New to C and having a hard time understanding pointers. I have an assignment that wants me to pass a word to a thread and then reverse the word. I've passed the word to the thread on into the function but I don't know how to iterate through it. What is the proper syntax?

```
void *reverse_string(void *str)
{
    // This function is called when the new thread is created
    printf("In funciton reverse_string(). The value is %s\n", str);
    char *p = (char *)str;  
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) // loop not working for printing elements in array
    {
        p[i] = i;
        printf("%s ....\n", p);
    }


    pthread_exit(NULL); // exit the thread
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* The main program creates a new thread and then exits. */
    pthread_t threadID;
    int status; 
    char * word = "SkAtIng";
    //char *p = word;

    printf("In function main(): Creating a new thread\n");
    // create a new thread in the calling process
    // a function name represents the address of the function
    status = pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, reverse_string, (void*) word);

    // After the new thread finish execution
    printf("In function main(): The new thread ID = %d\n", threadID);

    if (status != 0) {
        printf("Oops. pthread create returned error code %d\n", &status);
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? `p[i] = i;` That is of course not reversing anything. It's overwriting the string characters with indices. "I don't know how to iterate through it". Seems like you have the basic idea with the `for` loop. The logic is not correct but the syntax looks more or less fine. So please clarify your exact problem.

Comment: Are you in the same class as the person who posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480270/trying-to-create-a-multi-threaded-c-program-that-prints-a-string-in-reverse-orde) half an hour ago? :)

Comment: `char * word = "SkAtIng";` That is a string literal that is not modifiable. If you want the thread to be able to write to it do `char word[] = "SkAtIng";`. That creates a (writeable) array initialised with that string value.

Comment: Also, need a `pthread_join` in the main thread. Otherwise it will exit immediately after creating the thread and take the child thread out with it preventing the child from doing its thing.

Comment: I'm trying to print each element in the array. But I'm not sure how to access the elements when it comes to passing it as a pointer.

Comment: yes, the same class

Comment: To print each char change `printf("%s ....\n", p);` to `printf("%c\n", p[i]);`

Comment: before this comment: `// After the new thread finish execution` needs to be the statement: `pthread_join(  threadid, NULL );`  so the main function waits for the thread to exit.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_string(char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str) - 1, i;
    if (len <= 0)
        return;
    for (i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        char tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len - i];
        str[len - i] = tmp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char word[] = "SkAtIng";
    printf("original word: %s\n", word);
    reverse_string(word);
    printf("reversed word: %s\n", word);
    return 0;
}
```

?

Couple of nuances:

1. You don't need any threads
2. Defining `char *word = "blahblah"` assumes the string is read-only (aka const) data and normally is not writable (generating exception), unlike that `char word[] = "blah-blah"` allocates the array locally on the stack.
3. In `reverse_string()` finction we exchange **values**, not indecies